# Oracle SOA BPEL Partnerlink strange SSL error

Tags: web-services, oracle, soa, bpel

I have a partner link in a BPEL process that simply points to http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL

Clearly this Web Service is not SSL secured. However when I deploy my composite app Oracle complains with the following stack trace:

What could be causing this?

Thank you,
Alessandro Ferrucci

```
<May 18, 2013 12:08:40 PM EDT> <Warning> <oracle.fabric.common.wsdl> <BEA-000000> <Failed to load WSDL from WebServiceXStockQuoteServiceWrapper.wsdl due to: WSDLException: faultCode=INVALID_WSDL: Error reading import of oramds:/deployed-composites/default/StockQuoteBPEL_rev1.0/WebServiceXStockQuoteServiceWrapper.wsdl: oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.LocalizedWSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Failed to read wsdl file at: "http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL", caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException. : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target>
<May 18, 2013 12:08:40 PM EDT> <Error> <oracle.integration.platform> <SOA-20003> <Unable to register service.
oracle.fabric.common.FabricException: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=INVALID_WSDL: Error reading import of oramds:/deployed-composites/default/StockQuoteBPEL_rev1.0/WebServiceXStockQuoteServiceWrapper.wsdl: oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.LocalizedWSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Failed to read wsdl file at: "http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL", caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException. : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target: WSDLException: faultCode=INVALID_WSDL: Error reading import of oramds:/deployed-composites/default/StockQuoteBPEL_rev1.0/WebServiceXStockQuoteServiceWrapper.wsdl: oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.LocalizedWSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Failed to read wsdl file at: "http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL", caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException. : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at oracle.fabric.composite.model.CompositeModel.loadImports(CompositeModel.java:460)
at oracle.fabric.composite.model.CompositeModel.getWSDLManager(CompositeModel.java:205)
at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.soap.WebServiceEntryBindingComponent.getDefinition(WebServiceEntryBindingComponent.java:384)
at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.soap.WebServiceEntryBindingComponent.load(WebServiceEntryBindingComponent.java:199)
at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.soap.WebServiceEntryBindingComponent.load(WebServiceEntryBindingComponent.java:147)
at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.CompositeDeploymentConnection.deployServices(CompositeDeploymentConnection.java:161)
at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.CompositeDeploymentConnection.deploy(CompositeDeploymentConnection.java:92)
at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.CompositeDeploymentManagerImpl.initDeployment(CompositeDeploymentManagerImpl.java:185)
at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.CompositeDeploymentManagerImpl.load(CompositeDeploymentManagerImpl.java:63)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.DeploymentEventPublisher.invoke(DeploymentEventPublisher.java:86)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at $Proxy384.load(Unknown Source)
at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.StandaloneCompositeDeploymentCoordinatorImpl.coordinateCompositeDeployment(StandaloneCompositeDeploymentCoordinatorImpl.java:67)
at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.BaseDeployProcessor.deployNewComposite(BaseDeployProcessor.java:467)
at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.BaseDeployProcessor.deploySARs(BaseDeployProcessor.java:268)
at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.DeployProcessor.doDeployWork(DeployProcessor.java:203)
at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.DeployProcessor.doDeployWork(DeployProcessor.java:147)
at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.DeployProcessor.doDeploy(DeployProcessor.java:134)
at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.DeployProcessor.process(DeployProcessor.java:100)
at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.CompositeDeployerServlet.doPostInsideLoggingSession(CompositeDeployerServlet.java:221)
at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.CompositeDeployerServlet.doPost(CompositeDeployerServlet.java:130)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:324)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:324)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:163)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused By: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=INVALID_WSDL: Error reading import of oramds:/deployed-composites/default/StockQuoteBPEL_rev1.0/WebServiceXStockQuoteServiceWrapper.wsdl: oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.LocalizedWSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Failed to read wsdl file at: "http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL", caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException. : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseImport(WSDLReaderImpl.java:966)
at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseDefinition(WSDLReaderImpl.java:820)
at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:719)
at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:667)
at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:659)
at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:213)
at oracle.fabric.common.wsdl.WSDLManager.loadWSDL(WSDLManager.java:288)
at oracle.fabric.common.wsdl.WSDLManager.loadWSDL(WSDLManager.java:368)
at oracle.fabric.composite.model.CompositeModel.loadImports(CompositeModel.java:442)
at oracle.fabric.composite.model.CompositeModel.getWSDLManager(CompositeModel.java:205)
at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.soap.WebServiceEntryBindingComponent.getDefinition(WebServiceEntryBindingComponent.java:384)
at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.soap.WebServiceEntryBindingComponent.load(WebServiceEntryBindingComponent.java:199)
at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.soap.WebServiceEntryBindingComponent.load(WebServiceEntryBindingComponent.java:147)
at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.CompositeDeploymentConnection.deployServices(CompositeDeploymentConnection.java:161)
at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.CompositeDeploymentConnection.deploy(CompositeDeploymentConnection.java:92)
at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.CompositeDeploymentManagerImpl.initDeployment(CompositeDeploymentManagerImpl.java:185)
at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.CompositeDeploymentManagerImpl.load(CompositeDeploymentManagerImpl.java:63)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.DeploymentEventPublisher.invoke(DeploymentEventPublisher.java:86)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at $Proxy384.load(Unknown Source)
at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.StandaloneCompositeDeploymentCoordinatorImpl.coordinateCompositeDeployment(StandaloneCompositeDeploymentCoordinatorImpl.java:67)
at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.BaseDeployProcessor.deployNewComposite(BaseDeployProcessor.java:467)
at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.BaseDeployProcessor.deploySARs(BaseDeployProcessor.java:268)
at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.DeployProcessor.doDeployWork(DeployProcessor.java:203)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by my  firewall. Once I authenticated through the firewall evertyhing worked.
Thanks,